# Image doesn't display when control is assigned from static object

Tags: c#, image, winforms, user-controls

I'm making a card game in C# using WinForms. The problem I'm experiencing is preventing me from going forward because I want to add user-made content. The goal is to set images to card dynamically, from whatever resource/file declared. Let's take a look at my code.

Here is `ExpansionInit.cs`

```
public static Card CopperCard = new Card
{
    Name = "Copper",
    ID = 0,
    BuyValue = 0,
    Type = CardType.Treasure,
    TreasureValue = 1,
    StackCount = GetCardStack(0),
};
```

Here is `GameGUI.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Dominion.Expansions.Base;
using Dominion.Properties;

namespace Dominion
{
    public partial class GameGui : Form
    {

        public GameGui()
        {
            Game.StartGame();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //new HandGUI().Show();
            cardCopper = ExpansionInit.CopperCard;
            cardCopper.BackgroundImage = Resources._0_copper;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is `Card.cs`. I'm not very sure if including this part is important at all, but if you can find something within it that could be causing the problem

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Dominion.Cards
{
    public delegate void CardActivationHandler(Card c, Player p);
    [JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
    public sealed partial class Card : UserControl
    {
        // ReSharper disable once InconsistentNaming
        [JsonProperty]
        public int StackCount;
        [JsonProperty]
        public int ID;
        [JsonProperty]
        public int TreasureValue;
        [JsonProperty]
        public int VictoryValue;
        [JsonProperty]
        public int BuyValue;
        [JsonProperty]
        public CardType Type;
        [JsonProperty]
        public CardActivationHandler Handler;

        [JsonProperty]
        public new string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty]
        public new string Name { get; set; }
        public Card()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }

    public enum CardType
    {
        Victory, Treasure, Action, Other
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object needed to be readded `form1.Controls.Add(cardCopper)` and Location reset.